# changing the file attribute with multiple args using call method

Tags: python, subprocess

```
from subprocess import call

def change_attribute(filename,attrib):
try:
    call(["attrib ", attrib ,  filename])
except OSError as exception:
    raise exception

f1 = "D:\\Tests\\fileattrib\\file1.txt"
att = ["+s","+h"]
#att = "+s" // this works fine 
#time.sleep(5)
change_attribute(f1,att)
```

I have a function `change_attribute`() which changes the  file attributes.

In the above script, it works good if I replace the `'list' att` to `'string'` variable.

However it throws exception `"parameter format not correct`" if I pass the list att.

what change does it require to accept list as arugment to the method.   Please see me as novice in python. 
 Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call` expects an array of strings, not an array containing a string, an array of strings, and another string.

You can fix that by doing

```
call(["attrib"] + attrib + ["filename"])
```